# Javascript, appended CSS not working on Webkit

Tags: javascript, css, dom, webkit

Once again, I turn to the expertise of the crowd :-)

I have appended a new stylesheet like so:

```
var css = "#newElement { color: #ff0000 }";
style = document.createElement('style');
    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else { 
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

I then create a new div like so:

```
var newElement = document.createElement("div");
newElement.id = "newElement";
```

The new style works fine on Firefox (turns to red) but not on Webkit (Chrome/Safari)...
I dont have the means to test on IE...

Does anyone know if there is an issue with webkit that would cause this? or any tips on how I can get this to be compatible?

I need to change things like links and hover attributes so using the direct method of changing styles of a DOM object will not work and I do not have the option of using jQuery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dxATN/ works fine here, maybe you forgot to add the new div to the dom or used a javascript feature someplace else in the code that only works in firefox like `let`?

Comment: `parent.document` makes me wonder: is this cross-domain?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Its not cross domain, its in an iFrame referring to the parent (same domain). No console errors... I see that its working fine on the jsfiddle but still nothing on my end... not sure why

Comment: may be parent' head is still not ready?

Comment: @Cherniv, possible, but it seems that I would get an error stating that head was null

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747616/webkit-dynamically-created-stylesheet-when-does-it-really-load) has some info about dynamically created stylesheets.